# Copying TD value to dynamically created input inside a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with dynamically generated td's that contain text inputs and I need to get the value from the first td in the row and insert into one of the inputs depending on what I select in a `<select>`. This is trigger by a button.

So far I'm able to get the the value I need with first-child and from my select I have the value of the option same as the class of the inputs.

```js
$("#t_a").click(function() {
  var selected = $('select[name=t_r]').val();
  $("table tr").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).find('td:first-child').html();
    $(this).find('.' + selected).attr("value", s);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="t_r" name="t_r" style="width:200px;">
<option value="1234">Option 1234</option>
<option value="1235">Option 1235</option>
<option value="1236">Option 1236</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="t_a" id="t_a" value="Apply" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="a_1234" class="1234" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="a_1235" class="1235" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="a_1236" class="1236" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>321</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="b_1234" class="1234" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="b_1235" class="1235" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="b_1236" class="1236" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="c_1234" class="1234" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="c_1235" class="1235" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="c_1236" class="1236" value=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add the value attribute, even empty, in the input tag

Comment: it looks like you are setting the value of one of the inputs to contain html. Is that what you want? You may want     var s = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
    $(this).find('.' + selected).val(s);

Comment: @TimLewis Sorry, added the necessary code. Hope its complete now.

mankowitz the current code sometimes works and others it doesn't.

Comment: Much better! I'm not sure what your issue is though; you might need to include the code that dynamically generates your inputs. Currently, your code works just fine.

Comment: The first time I hit apply it all works fine, but after deleting an input it all stops working for a column.

Comment: `"after deleting an input it all stops working for a column"` - no, it doesn't - check the HTML via the "inspect element" tool and you'll see that the `value` attribute is still being updated, as this is what your code is doing: `.attr("value", s)`. If you want the value to visibly change, you'll have to call `.val(s)` instead.

Comment: Thank you @user7290573 this actually solved all my problems, didnt realize that the two worked differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of monkawitz and user7290573 I was able to solve my problem by using val() instead of attr().

Thank you Tim Lewis for the guidance.